# OpenStack Sahara installation over DevStack Juno

Tags: openstack

I am trying to install OpenStack Sahara on Juno DevStack.
I have followed instructions [here](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/sahara/userdoc/installation.guide.html).
All the installation is successful but I am getting some errors while I try to hit Sahara as followed.

```
2015-05-15 15:29:26.392 14677 DEBUG keystonemiddleware.auth_token [-] Removing headers from request environment: X-Service-Catalog,X-Identity-Status,X-Service-Identity-Status,X-Roles,X-Service-Roles,X-Domain-Name,X-Service-Domain-Name,X-Project-Id,X-Service-Project-Id,X-Project-Domain-Name,X-Service-Project-Domain-Name,X-User-Id,X-Service-User-Id,X-User-Name,X-Service-User-Name,X-Project-Name,X-Service-Project-Name,X-User-Domain-Id,X-Service-User-Domain-Id,X-Domain-Id,X-Service-Domain-Id,X-User-Domain-Name,X-Service-User-Domain-Name,X-Project-Domain-Id,X-Service-Project-Domain-Id,X-Role,X-User,X-Tenant-Name,X-Tenant-Id,X-Tenant _remove_auth_headers /home/arijit/openstack/sahara/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystonemiddleware/auth_token/__init__.py:677
2015-05-15 15:29:26.393 14677 DEBUG keystonemiddleware.auth_token [-] Authenticating user token __call__ /home/arijit/openstack/sahara/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystonemiddleware/auth_token/__init__.py:586
2015-05-15 15:29:26.396 14677 DEBUG keystoneclient.auth.identity.v2 [-] Making authentication request to http://127.0.0.1:35357/v2.0/tokens get_auth_ref /home/arijit/openstack/sahara/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneclient/auth/identity/v2.py:76
2015-05-15 15:29:26.688 14677 DEBUG keystoneclient.session [-] REQ: curl -g -i -X GET http://127.0.0.1:35357/v3/auth/tokens -H "X-Subject-Token: {SHA1}15cb6b90d131675addaee288ff2cd3072e2ea62f" -H "User-Agent: python-keystoneclient" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: {SHA1}993bf01862a371ba4b9e04a031765f9d4496046b" _http_log_request /home/arijit/openstack/sahara/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneclient/session.py:190
2015-05-15 15:29:26.766 14677 DEBUG keystoneclient.session [-] RESP: _http_log_response /home/arijit/openstack/sahara/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneclient/session.py:218
2015-05-15 15:29:26.768 14677 DEBUG keystoneclient.session [-] Request returned failure status: 403 request /home/arijit/openstack/sahara/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneclient/session.py:383
2015-05-15 15:29:26.769 14677 ERROR keystonemiddleware.auth_token [-] Bad response code while validating token: 403
2015-05-15 15:29:26.771 14677 WARNING keystonemiddleware.auth_token [-] Identity response: {"error": {"message": "You are not authorized to perform the requested action: identity:validate_token (Disable debug mode to suppress these details.)", "code": 403, "title": "Forbidden"}}
2015-05-15 15:29:26.771 14677 DEBUG keystonemiddleware.auth_token [-] Token validation failure. _validate_token /home/arijit/openstack/sahara/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystonemiddleware/auth_token/__init__.py:787
2015-05-15 15:29:26.771 14677 TRACE keystonemiddleware.auth_token Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-05-15 15:29:26.771 14677 TRACE keystonemiddleware.auth_token   File "/home/arijit/openstack/sahara/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystonemiddleware/auth_token/__init__.py", line 776, in _validate_token
2015-05-15 15:29:26.771 14677 TRACE keystonemiddleware.auth_token     expires = _get_token_expiration(data)
2015-05-15 15:29:26.771 14677 TRACE keystonemiddleware.auth_token   File "/home/arijit/openstack/sahara/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystonemiddleware/auth_token/__init__.py", line 406, in _get_token_expiration
2015-05-15 15:29:26.771 14677 TRACE keystonemiddleware.auth_token     raise exc.InvalidToken(_('Token authorization failed'))
2015-05-15 15:29:26.771 14677 TRACE keystonemiddleware.auth_token InvalidToken: Token authorization failed
2015-05-15 15:29:26.771 14677 TRACE keystonemiddleware.auth_token 
2015-05-15 15:29:26.774 14677 DEBUG keystonemiddleware.auth_token [-] Marking token as unauthorized in cache store_invalid /home/arijit/openstack/sahara/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystonemiddleware/auth_token/_cache.py:197
2015-05-15 15:29:26.775 14677 WARNING keystonemiddleware.auth_token [-] Authorization failed for token
2015-05-15 15:29:26.776 14677 INFO keystonemiddleware.auth_token [-] Invalid user token - rejecting request
2015-05-15 15:29:26.782 14677 INFO sahara.cli.sahara_all [-] 169.144.52.65 - - [15/May/2015 15:29:26] "GET /v2.0/9cc3dec80faf45c09bbb79e75edb855c/images HTTP/1.1" 401 197 0.389358
2015-05-15 15:29:40.743 14677 DEBUG sahara.openstack.common.periodic_task [-] Running periodic task SaharaPeriodicTasks.update_job_statuses run_periodic_tasks /home/arijit/openstack/sahara/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sahara/openstack/common/periodic_task.py:193
2015-05-15 15:29:40.748 14677 DEBUG sahara.service.periodic [-] Updating job statuses update_job_statuses /home/arijit/openstack/sahara/sahara-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sahara/service/periodic.py:75
```

Seems like keystone authentication error.
Can you please help on this.

Comment: Ok.. got the issue. there was mismatchingh user and tenant in the sahara.conf.